# Using ksop2 how to send large files to web service

Tags: java, android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

i have application that picks the file from a dedicated path on my device and sends it to server.

I m using ksoap2 lib to call .NET webservice to send my file to server. i am using Base 64 encoding.

I can send file with max size of 1MB without encryption and 850Kb with encryption. Encyrption algorithm i am using is 3DES.

If i try to send files larger than above size i get following error: Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:121)

My Test environment: Android emulator with API Level 8, Android 2.2 and SDCard memory 512 MB

Is it that i am missing out something? Can using BLOB help me in this scenario

Is there any way to send larger file? i have heard of sending data chunks but have no idea on that . any link or sample code will really help.

to get file data using following code:
here url = where file is stored

`public byte[] getFileData( String vURL){
        instream = new FileInputStream(vURL);
        size = (int) vURL.length();

        fileContent = new byte[size];
        instream.read(fileContent); 
    }`

Encode the data using following code:

```
byte[] res = Utilities.getFileData(file);
String mdata = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(res,                                android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
```

calling server side web service and sending data to server

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(nameSpace, methodName);

if (fileData != null && !fileData.equals("")) {
      request.addProperty("vBLOBData", fileData);
}
   SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = getEnvelope(request);
   HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(url); // ,3000
   ht.debug = true;
   ht.call(soapAction, envelope);
  response = (envelope.getResponse()).toString();
```

Not able to send filedata more than 1 MB.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your code. Any answer to this question is just speculation unless we can actually see some code.

Comment: Please Specify how much larger the files you are trying to send here, since if those file are larger than 4 mb then the problem is not in your android part its all in your web service part and you need to configure your web.Config file by setting the following attributes <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="Max_File_Size" executionTimeout="Max_Execution_Time" />.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but why you don't divide your file into parts and send each part individually into a loop or into an `android background service` using a timer that sends a part every x seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your buffer to 1024 before sending it , its about the limit of your buffer size and your ram

Answer (score 0):

Use GZip Zipping algorithm to zip large file from mobile side; use same unzipping from server.

Also use MultipartEntity can help to upload large file content.

Answer (score 0):

If compression doesn't help - as mentioned in previous post - you will probably have to segment the message yourself.

[Segmentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581243/read-a-segment-of-a-file-in-java-android)